# Problems with Hibernate ORM in H2

Tags: java, orm, h2, hibernate-mapping

I have a project which uses Hibernate and H2 Database. There's an H2-database file in the project directory. This DB file contains a table, Person. I can insert or remove data to/from this table using the H2 console, But the problem is that when I try to get an object from this table by Hibernate framework I will get this error:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "PERSON" not found; SQL statement:
select person0_.ID as ID1_0_0_, person0_.NAME as NAME2_0_0_, person0_.PHONE_NUMBER as PHONE_NU3_0_0_ from person person0_ where person0_.ID=? [42102-197]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:357)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:5920)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableFilter(Parser.java:1430)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimpleFromPart(Parser.java:2138)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimple(Parser.java:2287)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSub(Parser.java:2133)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectUnion(Parser.java:1946)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelect(Parser.java:1919)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:463)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:335)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:307)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:278)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:611)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:549)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1247)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.<init>(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:76)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:304)
```

Here is the hibernate.cfg.xml file:

```
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/orm/cfg">
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:h2:C:\Users\Amir\Desktop\hibernate\src\main\resources\test</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.h2.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.username">sa</property>
        <property name="connection.password"></property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

, Person POJO:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private String id;
    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "PHONE_NUMBER")
    private String phoneNumber;

    public Person() {}

    public Person(String name, String id, String phoneNumber) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) { this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber; }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return this.phoneNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person {Name= " + name + ", ID= " + id + ", Phone number= " + phoneNumber + "}";
    }

}
```

And finally, hibernate connection configuration class:

```
public class PersonDAO {
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    static {
        try {
            sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().addAnnotatedClass(Person.class).buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public PersonDAO() {

    }

    public static void insertRecord(Person person) {
        try (Session session = sessionFactory.openSession()) {
            session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(person);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        }
    }

    public static Person getRecord(String id) {
        try (Session session = sessionFactory.openSession()) {
            return session.find(Person.class, id);
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea about this problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check capitalization of your table name. You annotated `@Table(name = "person")` and you report that table `Person` exists. As far as I remember, H2 uses case sensitive table names.

Comment: what did you change? what is the table name and what is your annotation now? And what is the direct query that works? Perhaps edit your question

Comment: I changed both the Table name and annotation name to "PERSON", but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Update the code snippets to show your latest changes. Also, show the manual H2 query that successfully retrieves records from the database.

Comment: Your exception shows that the table is not found. Maybe your Java program resets your schema? Try to use the H2 console, insert records, verify they are there.  Then run your java program, copy the exception if it happens again. Then use the H2 console again and verify the records you inserted before are still there